# map XML to c#objects with multiple levels using LinqToXML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file looks like this:

```
<Student>
    <Id> 10010</id>
    <Name>AAA</Name>
    <Gender>F</Gender>
    <Tags>
        <HobbyTags>
            <Tag>Reading</Tag>
            <Tag>Movies</Tag>
            <Tag>Jogging</Tag>
         </HobbyTags>
         <MajorTags>
            <Tag>Math</Tag>
            <Tag>Literature</Tag>
         </MajorTags> 
     </Tags>
</Student>
<Student>... </Student>
<Student>... </Student>
<Student>... </Student>
```

and I have existing c# objects like this:

```
public class Tag
{   
    public string tag {get; set;}
}
public class HobbyTags 
{
    List<Tag> hobbyTags {get; set;}
}
public class MajorTags 
{
    List<Tag> majorTags {get; set;}
}
public class Tags
{
    public HobbyTags hobbyTags {get; set;}
    public MajorTags majorTags {get; set;}
}
public class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Gender {get; set;}
    public Tags tags {get; set;}
}

public class Students
{
    public List<Student> students {get; set;}
}
```

now I'm using linqToXML to map the xml and c# objects, to put the value in xml into its corresponding fields in data objects. my questions is I know how to set the first level fields like Id, Name, Gender, but I'm not sure how to set the values for the inside levels like HobbyTags, MajorTags. except for the id, other fields in xml can be null. any advice? thanks!

Comment: XDocuments contain XElements which may contain more XElements, XAttributes, or content as a string. You should be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*<Students>
<Student>
    <Id> 10011</Id>
    <Name>AAA</Name>
    .......
</Student>
</Students>
*/


var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\students.xml");
Students students = new Students();

students.students = xdoc.Descendants("Student").Select (x => new Student {
  Id = int.Parse(x.Element("Id").Value),
  Name = x.Element("Name").Value,
  Gender = x.Element("Gender").Value,
  tags = new Tags{
   hobbyTags = new HobbyTags{
    hobbyTags = x.Element("Tags").Element("HobbyTags").Descendants("Tag").Select (t => new Tag{ tag =  t.Value}).ToList()       
   },
   majorTags = new MajorTags{
    majorTags = x.Element("Tags").Element("MajorTags").Descendants("Tag").Select (t => new Tag{ tag =  t.Value}).ToList()       
   },
  }

}).ToList()
```

;

```
public class Tag
{   
    public string tag {get; set;}
}
public class HobbyTags 
{
   public List<Tag> hobbyTags {get; set;}
}
public class MajorTags 
{
    public List<Tag> majorTags {get; set;}
}
public class Tags
{
    public HobbyTags hobbyTags {get; set;}
    public MajorTags majorTags {get; set;}
}
public class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Gender {get; set;}
    public Tags tags {get; set;}
}

public class Students
{
    public List<Student> students {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: By the way, I recommend using PascalCase for naming public properties.